# Spring roo project, header binding

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, binding, jspx

I'm new to spring mvc and spring projects.

I've created new spring roo project. I the header.jspx I've noticed use of binding

```
<a href="${home}" name="${fn:escapeXml(home_label)}" title="${fn:escapeXml(home_label)}">
  <img src="${banner}" />
</a>
```

Where are variables home, home_label, banner defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a few lines above:

```
<spring:url var="banner" value="/resources/images/banner-graphic.png" />
<spring:url var="home" value="/" />
<spring:message code="button_home" var="home_label" />
<a href="${home}" name="${fn:escapeXml(home_label)}" title="${fn:escapeXml(home_label)}">
    <img src="${banner}" />
</a>
```

These variables are results of `<spring:url>` and `<spring:message>` tags exported as variables. Using attriubte named `var` to specify variable names is a common pattern for such cases.

`<spring:url>` prepends the given path with application's context path if necessary in order to produce absolute path. `<spring:message>` exrtacts a message with a given key from `.properties` files used for localization.